# Altered table structures not available in database diagram (localdb)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using Management Studio 17.8.1 I added a column to my table saved and refreshed.

However when I create a database diagram making use of the table, the column is missing.

Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

[Update]

The following table will display in the designer

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [smallId] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[Update]

Strangely the designer is even showing deleted tables.
Closing MMSM and re-opening will allow the diagrams to use the new structures.

Could it be a bug in localdb ?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried altering a table I got a message

```
  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has detected that an operation is blocking user input. 
  This can be caused by an active modal dialog or a task that needs to block user interaction.
```